# BitBucket API get repository admins

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm having a team in BitBucket which has around 200+ members & 500 repositories. I wanted do some auditing of all repos & using BitBucket API for most of my work. I came across a requirement where I need to find out Admin members of each repos ( even one repo at a time will do), I read documentation but didn't find anything useful.
Can someone could guide me on this.

Thanks,
Meghanand

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server? Despite the name, they're separate products with different API's

Comment: @daveruinseverything thanks for replying, well I was not aware of this before , well we are using BitBucket cloud.

Answer (score 1):

There's this rest api defined to get the users of a repository with their permissions in the below link for BitBucket stash.

`/rest/api/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/permissions/users`.

May be this can be extended to BitBucket Cloud.

https://docs.atlassian.com/DAC/rest/stash/3.11.3/stash-rest.html#idp494288